# jQuery UI Selectable - do not unselect fields on click of certain element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm currently building a document editor making use of jQuery UI Selectable. In the editor you can add multiple draggable fields. If one or multiple fields are selected, an options menu at the top appears, which shows a few clickable options (e.g. bold, italic, etc.). The problem is that when this menu is clicked, all fields are deselected automatically.

Does anybody have an idea about how to prvenet this?

Here's my very basic implementation:

```
$("section.window").selectable({filter: "li.draggable"});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add a working example (jsfiddle/snippet)

Comment: @Dekel: https://jsfiddle.net/aaa7sun8/29/ - here's one!

Comment: @Dekel: I would like the elements not to be deselected when clicking on the link "NO DESELECT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the selectable on the `ul` element and not on the container element:

```js
$( "#selezionabile" ).selectable({
    selected: function( e, ui ) {
        if ($( ui.selected ).hasClass( "ui-state-highlight" )) {
            $( ui.selected ).removeClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
        } else {
            $( ui.selected ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
        }
    },    
    unselected: function( e, ui ) {
      $( ui.unselected ).removeClass( "ui-state-highlight" );    
    }
});
```

```css
ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; width: 50%;}
ul li {padding: 0.4em; margin: 2em; cursor: pointer; font-size: 0.8em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="contianer">
  <a style="display: block; background: #ffc" href="javascript:void(0)">NO DESELECT</a>
  <ul id="selezionabile" class="ui-widget">
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">Elemento 1</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">Elemento 2</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">Elemento 3</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">Elemento 4</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">Elemento 5</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">Elemento 6</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">Elemento 7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you set the `selectable()` on the container - evething inside that container can cause the select/deselect (and this is not what you are looking for).