# jQuery UI selectable widget multiple unselect with mouse drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I am using jQuery UI selectable widget. I saw a solution at [Is there a way to change event parameters in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215333/is-there-a-way-to-change-event-parameters-in-jquery) to enable multiple selection (with mouse drag) which works fine. Now I am trying to get the similar feature to unselect multiple elements which doesn't work.

```
$('#selectlist').on("mousedown", function (e) {
    e.metaKey = true; //multiple select true
    //e.ctrlKey = true;
}).selectable({
    filter: '.select-li',
    selecting: function (event, ui) {
        debugger;
        //if ($(ui.selecting).hasClass('li-planned')) {
        //    $(ui.selecting).removeClass("ui-selecting");
        //}
    },
    unselecting: function (event, ui) {
        //if ($(ui.unselecting).hasClass('li-planned')) {
        //    $(ui.unselecting).removeClass("ui-unselecting").addClass('ui-selected');
        //}
    },
    stop: function (event) {
        //debugger;
        //do some work here
    }
})
```

I tried multiple options to achieve but so far I am not able to get it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the supporting html too?

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853372/jquery-ui-selectable-do-not-unselect-fields-on-click-of-certain-element

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#selectable").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
    e.metaKey = true;
  }).selectable();
  $("#selectable").selectable({
    selected: function(event, ui) {
      if (!$(ui.selected).hasClass('selected-flag')) {
        $(ui.selected).addClass('selected-flag');
      } else {
        $(ui.selected).removeClass("ui-selected selected-flag");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#feedback {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}
#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}
#selectable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}
#selectable li {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="demo">
  <ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
  </ol>

</div>
```

I've created a solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aminur/ZfevM/427/) and also added snippet in my answer. Here I've added a flag class to elements on select event to identify later which items were selected and then remove both `ui-selected` and flag class from them, which then make it unselected. I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have been doing same thing after I did some more research but it looks like a hack rather than a permanent solution. Thats why I put a bounty so that if there are any built in functionality I can leverage instead of calling the selected event and there unselect something.

Comment: in you're question, you've said that you were not able to achieve this

Comment: This looks like a valid solution, I don't know that there is a more "built in" way to accomplish this then tapping into the "selected" event.

Comment: Trevor, you are right. Aminur's reply is the closest I got so far. Its just I was looking to get more native approach. I am closing this bounty on this now. thanks Aminur.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make your list selectable by

```
 $( "#selectlist" ).selectable();
```

**You can multiple select on selectables without using your mouse down**.

1. Mouse drag
2. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while **selecting**.

**On unselecting multiple (based on selecting above)**,

1.a. Select one, and all the others will unselect 
1.b. Select an empty area in you list (ei. space between list1 and list2), and all will unselect 
2. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while **unselecting**.

See jQuery-ui's demo http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#default

Comment: the demo URL doesn't support multiple unselect. Also as I mentioned before, I want to keep the selection when I click again on the lists. Thats why I am setting `e.metaKey = true`.

Answer (score 0):

I think Aminur answered your question based on the information given.  That's probably what I would have thought you were after before before reading your feedback under his answer.

Here is another proposal.  This proposal basically clears all the selected items if a user starts to drag on an **already** selected item.  Maybe this is what you are after when you say you are looking to deselect multiple elements.

```
$(function() {
  $("#selectable").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
    if(e.target.className.indexOf('ui-selected') === -1){
        e.metaKey = true;
    }
  }).selectable();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfevM/428/)